# Find across 2 down 3

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, excel-2016

I am working on a few stats at work and changing the way we obtain/store data. I have solved most my problems but the final one eludes me. The format is as below.

```
Name 1    - Title - Title 2

Week 1  - value 1 - value 2 

Week 2  - value 1 - value 2 

Name 2    - Title - Title 2

Week 1  - value 1 - value 2 

Week 2  - value 1 - value 2
```

I know how to find Title and Title 2 based on the Name. But I need to be able to pull Week 2 value 1, or Week 2 value 2 based on the name. So search - then get value across x and by y. Preferably without vba cos I get lost with that.

I've been using index match for the horizontal lookup in normal cells, I think I could use both horiztonal & veritcal but I've had no success im not sure if this is because Week 1 / Week 2 are fixed and occur multiple times.

Comment: try using the offset formula?

Comment: Match the name and then +2?

Comment: I tried using off-set. 
But because its a repeating pattern Week 1 or Week 2 become duplicates so its not A1:A3 for example, it needs to be A1:C7 to reference to entire table 

I can specify vertical as A1:A7 to find the name, but the horizontal could be on row A or D etc 

I may be missing something but I literally have been developing the excel file for 18hours and im worried im too close to the problem im misisng the obvious lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return, for instance, "Value2" of "Week2" when you are searching for "Name 2" you could use:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Name 2",A:A,0)), 2, 2)
```

`INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Name 2",A:A,0))` will return the cell reference where "Name 2" occurs in Column `A`. `=Offset()` will then go two rows down and two columns over and return the value.

Comment: Perfect, I was using Offset before but couldnt for the life of me get it to work, your solution dropped right in and functioned perfectly in a way I can easily tweak for other sections! Thankyou!